# How to use make_unique in clang 3.4?

Tags: c++, clang, c++14

Using `Travis-CI` I'm trying to build a C++ project that uses `std::make_unique`. However I get a build error:

```
no member named 'make_unique' in namespace 'std'
            mFiles.emplace_back(std::make_unique<File>(*this, rec));
```

I have included `memory`, and this code compiles in VS2013 and gcc 4.8 with `-std=c++14`. If I use this flag in clang 3.4 I get an error:

```
error: invalid value 'c++14' in '-std=c++14'
```

According the the clang docs:

http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html

I should be using `-std=c++1y` but this still yeilds the same `no member named 'make_unique' in namespace 'std'`. So how do I get it to work?

Comment: try use -std=c++1y instead -std=c++14

Comment: Read my last sentence, this yields the same error

Comment: Are you sure this is a c++14 feature? I would think it also exists in c++11. Tried ``-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++``?

Comment: @user2225104 it is C++14 feature.

Comment: what is yours value of `__cplusplus` macro?
Try also `clang++ main.cpp  -std=c++1y -stdlib=libc++`

Comment: is `#include <memory>` present?

Comment: "I have included memory" so yes, how can I check __cplusplus value? Also not working with -std=c++11

Comment: Funny. I get the same effect on my freebsd with clang++ 3.4.1 if using -std=c++11. But it works for me if using -std=c++1y.

Comment: What C++ library are you using?

Comment: Whatever the default is?

Comment: So I said that you should try without default `clang++ main.cpp -std=c++1y -stdlib=libc++`

Comment: This caused all headers not to be found, but the answer of upgrading libstdc++ worked for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does not depend on the compiler, but on the standard library implementation. `std::make_unique` is not a core language feature, but a library function.

Check the version of `libstdc++` used by Travis.

---

According to [the GCC 4.9 changelog](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html), `std::make_unique` was introduced into `libstdc++` around the time of release of GCC 4.9.

If Travis is using a version of GCC prior to 4.9, it's very probable that its `libstdc++` version does not have `std::make_unique` yet.

Comment: I upgraded gcc to 4.9 on travis which pulled in new libstdc++, now make_unique works in clang with -std=c++1y

Comment: I installed the `libstdc++-6-dev` package along with `clang-6.0` and got my build working. I needed to add sources `llvm-toolchain-trusty-6.0` and `ubuntu-toolchain-r-test` for that version.